# LiveStream has different "stream name" when created from LiveStream API PHP (checked API result, with API Explorer and also YouTube page)

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

Am I doing something wrong, or do we have a bug in LiveStream API? How can three different sources show three different live stream names for the very same Ingestion?

By some reason, the inserted LiveStream object comes with a response
that does not match YouTube Web Page.

Sections of this question:

- PHP Code for live stream
- API Result into $liveStream
- PHP Code for broadcast insert & binding
- Response into $bindBroadcastResponse
- YouTube LiveStream API Explorer
- Recap
- And the result in YouTube page does not match

**PHP Code for live stream**

```
$streamSnippet = new \Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStreamSnippet();
$streamSnippet->setTitle($cameraName);

$cdn = new \Google_Service_YouTube_CdnSettings();
$cdn->setFormat($cameraName);
$cdn->setIngestionType('rtmp');

$streamInsert = new \Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStream();
$streamInsert->setSnippet($streamSnippet);
$streamInsert->setCdn($cdn);
$streamInsert->setKind('youtube#liveStream');

$liveStream = $youtube->liveStreams->insert('snippet,cdn',$streamInsert, array());
```

**API Result into $liveStream**

```
Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStream Object
(
    [cdnType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_CdnSettings
    ...
    [etag] => "5C5HHOaBSHC5ZXfkrT4ZlRCi01A/lY9i12sOWOAkTwfchEAQUxEWdX8"
    [id] => UOzxsX96_We6MrMTsP5RiA1480670405575117
    [kind] => youtube#liveStream
    ...
    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
            ...    
            [cdn] => Array
                (
                    [format] => 1440p
                    [ingestionType] => rtmp
                    [ingestionInfo] => Array
                        (
                            [streamName] => 9zfr-ggd9-brtf-XXXX
                            [ingestionAddress] => rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2
                            [backupIngestionAddress] => rtmp://b.rtmp.youtube.com/live2?backup=1
                        )
                    [resolution] => 1440p
                    [frameRate] => 30fps
                )
        )
    ...
)
```

**PHP Code for broadcast insert & binding**

```
$broadcastInsert = new \Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();
$broadcastInsert->setSnippet($broadcastSnippet);
$broadcastInsert->setStatus($status);
$broadcastInsert->setKind('youtube#liveBroadcast');
$broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,status',$broadcastInsert, array());

$bindBroadcastResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->bind($broadcastsResponse['id'],'id,contentDetails',array('streamId' => $liveStream['id'],));
```

**Response into $bindBroadcastResponse**

```
Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast Object
(
    ...
    [etag] => "5C5HHOaBSHC5ZXfkrT4ZlRCi01A/_2Jev_YmRlYUwMBX1ptq_Kp8uVs"
    [id] => idd8f7dSLzk
    [kind] => youtube#liveBroadcast
    ...
    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
            [contentDetails] => Array
                (
                    [boundStreamId] => UOzxsX96_We6MrMTsP5RiA1480670405575117
                    ...
                )    
        )    
)
```

**YouTube LiveStream API Explorer**

If I list all the streams later, using [LiveStream API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list), see image below, I got a third different result (see code below).

[image]

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#liveStreamListResponse",
 "etag": "\"5C5HHOaBSHC5ZXfkrT4ZlRCi01A/RGcoFd2XK9IZmX0hgw_pFxuaeC4\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#liveStream",
   "etag": "\"5C5HHOaBSHC5ZXfkrT4ZlRCi01A/d-ptvs6HC_oItk2Kv2PtrovurCk\"",
   "id": "UOzxsX96_We6MrMTsP5RiA1480670405575117",
   "snippet": ...,
   "cdn": {
    "format": "1440p",
    "ingestionType": "rtmp",
    "ingestionInfo": {
     "streamName": "1wzh-zjwb-b0fr-XXXX",
     "ingestionAddress": "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2",
     "backupIngestionAddress": "rtmp://b.rtmp.youtube.com/live2?backup=1"
    },
    "resolution": "1440p",
    "frameRate": "30fps"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

**Recap**

```
PHP-> Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast[id] => idd8f7dSLzk
PHP-> Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStream->modelData[cdn][ingestionInfo][streamName] => 9zfr-ggd9-brtf-XXXX
API Explorer -> items[0].cdn.ingestionInfo.streamName => "1wzh-zjwb-b0fr-XXXX"
```

**And the result in YouTube page does not match**

[image: LiveStream id does not match the one I got from creation]

Comment: I know this might look similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235664/difference-in-ingestation-settings-creating-a-live-event-using-youtube-api-vs-we?rq=1, but it is not. That thread is from long time ago and does not apply anymore. API at that time was at v2, now it's at v3 (and I'm using v3 api)

Comment: Just opened a defect at Google: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8814&q=label%3AAPi-YouTube&sort=-id&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary

Comment: Still happening....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **very** long time, someone replied the bug I have filled to Google.

This is the response from [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=8814):

> It's not necessarily expected for the stream key provided by the API
>   to match the stream key provided by the user interface. However, if
>   the two stream keys are different, both should work.
>
> Please respond on this bug if you're seeing an issue where the stream
>   keys are different and only one of them works.

The thing is that I had tried previously to cast using the stream name I got from the API, but it had not worked.

Testing now, it works.